# I`m trying to make google chart responsive for all devices size

Tags: javascript, responsive, pygooglechart

I have in my webApp charts that generated automatically hold data from Google analytics but it's not responsive for all devices

JavaScript code:

```
 var dataChart1 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      'ids': 'ga:789456123', // <-- Replace with the ids value for your view.
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
      'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
      'filters': 'ga:pagePath==<?php echo $page; ?>',
      'dimensions': 'ga:date'
    },
    chart: {
      'container': 'chart-1-container',
      'type': 'LINE',
      'options': {
        'width': '40%'
      }
    }
  });
  dataChart1.execute();
```

Generated in HTML div tag:

```
   <div id="chart-1-container" style="width:100%l height:100%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind a `window Resize` event listener, and redraw the chart on resize

eg, using Jquery..

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    redrawMychart() // impement this method which calls draw() method
});
```

Edit:
Since you are using Embedded Api ..
calling `dataChart1.execute();`  will do the job for you in window resize.

Note: since it will be redrawn everytime the window gets resized, look for smart resize options to prevent multiple redraws.

Comment: Thanks for you response but I`m not draw chart the chart generated by google analytics where I should  call this method and how ?

Comment: Did you mean replace chartname.execute with the function windows.resize ?? and in the body of function call chartname,execute ?

Comment: @mousa.Alshaikh, I meant, call `dataChart1.execute();` on `window's .resize` event, Given your `dataChart1` variable should be accessible in that scope, Either make it `global` or create a new variable in `local scope` with same settings.

Comment: Thanks, I`ll try it

Comment: It's work but not for all charts I have chart with GEO type and another  one with pie chart whats wrong with resize function it's work on line charts only ??

Comment: No, it should have worked for both, you need to call .execute() for both the instances

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it can help you better

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    drawChart();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I`ll try it

Comment: For better understanding and uses, please have a look on this [https://codepen.io/flopreynat/pen/BfLkA](https://codepen.io/flopreynat/pen/BfLkA)